# Resolve and q.All() issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-promise

I am trying to resolve a method like below using `ui-router`

```
$stateProvider
        .state('abc', {
            url: 'xyz',
            templateUrl: 'templateURL',
            controller: ctrl,
            resolve:{
                data: function(someService){
                    data = someService.init();
                    return data;
                }
            }
        })
```

And my service code looks like this

```
var someObject = {
  data1: ...,
  data2: ....,
  ...
}
return{
   init: function(){
   promise1 = ...
   promise2 = ...
   promise3 = $http.get('someurl').then(function(){
   ...
   ...
   //do some manipulation with someObj
   return someObject;
   });
   $q.all(promise1 , promise2 ).then(promise3);
   }
}
```

When I debug the code, it is coming to line `return someObject` but then it is not resolving.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ofcourse you are not returning a promise from init function, then why would resolve wait. It will just resolve instaneously

Comment: Then should I return q?

Comment: Just do  `return $q.all([promise1 , promise2] ).then(promise3);` and from resolve just `return someService.init()`

Comment: Basically all 3 promises should be resolved and someObject should be populated before i go on with the route

Comment: oh ok, I will try that thanks

Comment: @PSL : No its still not working... thanks for your help though

Comment: Promise 3 is just as promise 1 and 2,  return $q. All([promise1, promise2, promise3])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `promise3` to only execute after `promise1` and `promise2` then try

```
return $q.all([promise1, promise2])
    .then(function(arrayOfData) {
        return promise3;
    });
```

Here is an example to illustrate the difference:

```
    var promise1 = $timeout(function() {
        return 'promise1Data';
    }, 1000); 
    var promise2 = $timeout(function() {
        return 'promise2Data';
    }, 2000);
    var promise3 = $timeout(function() {
        return 'promise3Data';
    }, 5000);

    // This is what you're essentially doing when your route resolves
    $q.all([promise1, promise2])
        .then(promise3)
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data); // You get ["promise1Data", "promise2Data"]
        });

    // This is what I think you want
    $q.all([promise1, promise2])
        .then(function(arrayOfResolvedData) {
            return promise3;
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data); // You get promise3Data
        });
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake... I made something wrong.. your solution works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must pass callback *functions* to `.then(…)`. Your `promise3` is none.

I suspect you wanted to do

```
return $q.all([promise1, promise2, promise3])
```

Comment: @AbhijithNagaraja: Maybe one of them is rejecting? Or one is pending forever?