# Angular - How do I wait for two queries when the second depends on results from the first?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get two result sets from different databases. The second result depends on parameters retrieved from the first result set. I want to make sure both result sets are returned before proceeding. Looking at some other questions, I thought perhaps this would work:

```
app.factory('myService',['$http','$q',function ($http, $q){

        function getDetails(scope){
            var paths = [];
            return $q.all([
                $http.post('getdetails.php',{begDate:scope.begDate, endDate:scope.endDate})
                .then(function(response) {
                     angular.forEach(response.data,function(table,key){
                        angular.forEach(table, function(row,key){
                            paths.push(row.CURRENT_PATH);
                        })
                     })
                     return response;
                 })
            ,
                $http.post('coordtest.php', {paths: paths})
                .then(function(response) {
                    return response;
                })
            ]);

        }

        return {
            getDetails: getDetails
        };
}]);
```

But the results of both get returned while paths is still empty?

Comment: `$.q.all()` isn't going to make the second request wait on the first...they will run simultaneously

Comment: @charlietfl thank you for the response, can you tell me how I can achieve that behavior?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000037/resolve-and-q-all-issue/32000637#32000637), it should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you cannot make the second request until you retrieve data from the first request. However, you want the promise of the second request returned. This is possible, but `$q.all` isn't quite the right fit (it's more useful for scenarios where all requests can be sent at once.)

What you seem to actually be after is having one request (**B**) rely on the results of another (**A**), but to return the promise of **B** so that its results can be used. This is possible using `$q.defer` to create a wrapper promise using the following pattern:

```
var response = $q.defer();
$http.get('a').success(function(data){
    $http.get('b', data).then(response.resolve, response.reject);
});
return response.promise;
```

In your code, this may look something like:

```
app.factory('myService',['$http','$q',function ($http, $q){

    function httpGetDetails(scope){
        return $http.post('getdetails.php',{
            begDate:scope.begDate, 
            endDate:scope.endDate
        });
    }    

    function parseDetails(response){
        return response.reduce(function(parsedResults, table){
            var paths = table.map(function(row){
                return row.CURRENT_PATH;
            });
            return parsedResults.concat(paths);
        }, []);
    } 

    function getDetails(scope){
        var result = $q.defer();

        var getDetailsRequest = httpGetDetails(scope);

        getDetailsRequest.success(function(response){
            var paths = parseDetails(response);

            $http.post('coordtest.php', {paths: paths})
                   .success(result.resolve) // Both requests succeeded
                   .error(result.reject);  // coordtest.php failed
        });

        // getdetails.php failed. 
        // Consider sending params that make it more obvious which failed
        getDetailsRequest.error(result.reject);

        return result.promise;
    }

    return {
        getDetails: getDetails
    };
}]);
```

Obviously, you can clean up the functions a bit, but it's a simple gist for chaining promises.

The idea is that you create a longer running promise, and manually resolve it based on the inner (second) request's results. This is similar to returning the `coordtest` response from your `myService` factory, except that it's feasible (you cannot synchronously return the `$http` promise made in an asynchronous function, so you make do and create a masking promise ahead of time).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. This makes sense, though can I use the results from both promises A and B, after returning the promise from B?

Comment: Sure, just include them in the `resolve` for **B**. Something like `.success(function(dataB){ response.resolve({ resultsA: data, resultsB: dataB }); });`. The world is your oyster in that inner-success function, send back any data you want. (But, of course, use more descriptive variable names than I just wrote in a real system. Maybe `{ paths: paths, coords: coords }` or something).